# How can i ping mysql clients?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, .net

How can I create a server side script to ping clients on mysql and windows form to see if they are still logged in?
For example ping a client and they have to do something in return to verify that they are still online.

Comment: Mysql connections are persistent, so if a client goes offline, it will terminate the connection. You can also set timeouts for idle connections.

Comment: Sorry I should of specified more. So on the log in screen of my windows application i log into a user table in mysql database and i simply record that by a entry called 'islogged' and when the application exits, i update that table islogged = 'NO'. However if the user for example looses internet connection before exiting the application that entry reamins at islogged = 'NO' and then they cannot log back on at a later stage because i check if the user is logged on before allowing them to log in

Comment: If you have a two-tiered application (client - database), then there is not much you can do about this without significantly rewriting your clients. If you have a three-tiered application (client - application server - database), then you can incorporate this feature in the application server layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly ping client from server, but there are some options.

### About timeouts

I think in any case you have to use server side timeout (wait_timeout), this timeout can be set server wide or upon connecting from the client, ex:

```
SET SESSION wait_timeout = 60
```

This is required because client can suddenly disappear without even closing tcp connection and explicit timeout will help mysql to close connection and free resources after wait_timeout seconds of client inactivity. According to [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) default timeout is rather large: 28800 seconds.

There is a drawback. If during normal operation your client may be inactive for more than wait_timeout seconds then either the client should know how to deal with closed connection (reconnect when database tells it has gone away) or it should send "ping" queries (like `select 1`) at least every `wait_timeout - 1` seconds.

## Using get_lock() function

Since mysql 5.7(and also in mariadb since 10.0.2) you can use multiple [user-level locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html).

> A lock obtained with GET_LOCK() is released explicitly by executing RELEASE_LOCK() or implicitly when your session terminates (either normally or abnormally). Locks obtained with GET_LOCK() are not released when transactions commit or roll back.

So the idea is to issue get_lock query upon client connection, ex:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('logged_in_{CLIENT_ID}', timeout)
```

You can set timeout to 0 and immediately tell that client cannot login, or you can wait (blocking) at most wait_timeout seconds to be sure that there is really another client holding the lock.

This lock will be released automatically by server when client disconnects or after wait_timeout of inactivity.
If lock is free get_lock() will return `1` otherwise (after waiting timeout seconds) will return `0`

## Using process id

If you don't want to use locks, PID of process can be used.

When client connects instead of writing `islogged = 'YES'` you can use current CONNECTION_ID() as a value.
Before logging in you can check that there is no active process for current client like this

```
SELECT islogged FROM logged
INNER JOIN information_schema.processlist ON
    processlist.id = logged.islogged
WHERE
   client_id = ...
```

And if above query returns nothing you then may upsert new pid into logged table

```
REPLACE INTO logged SET islogged = CONNECTION_ID(), client_id = ...
```

I would prefer to use get_lock() because it seems easier, does not suffer from concurrency issues and allows to implement waiting.

Don't forget that timeouts are essential and you have to deal with reconnection or send regular pings to avoid unexpected "server has gone away" issues in client.